# How should worker processes listen on same port

Tags: qt, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to write a simple Web Server in QT which will handle HTTP requests.
I know QT has QThreads and I can use it for handling simultaneous connections.
What I want is to have atleast 2 worker processes so that I can pass most of the load of the requests from the master to the workers.
The problem is the master is listening on port 80 and it does the "accept" when there is an incoming connection.
How should I write the code for the worker to accept an incoming connection ?
The worker process cannot listen on the same port as the master binds to the port 80.

I know NGinx and LigHTTPD have worker processes and it is only the master that listens on the port 80.
Please let me know how should I do this or how does NGINX or Lighttpd implement this.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

- The master process does not accept connections on the socket but the workers do. When a connection comes in, it will be `accept()`ed by one of the workers at random. You can't control which of the workers which are blocked on `accept()` will receive it.
- Only the master process accepts connections. Then the master process dispatches the accepted connections to the workers over another socket using `sendmsg()` with `SCM_RIGHTS`. You could have a bunch of `socketpair()`s, one between the master and each worker, to accomplish this.

If you are using worker threads rather than worker processes, then you don't have to use the `SCM_RIGHTS` on a socket trick to send the accepted connections to workers because the file descriptors are already valid in the worker thread (there is no separate file descriptor namespace for separate threads of a single process). In this case you can just use simple signaling like a semaphore and a queue to let the worker know it should pick up a new connection.

Comment: But how will the worker process listen on the same port if the master is listening on the same port ? Also how can a worker process accept() a connection if its not listening ? Is there any example you can give me for the first and the second method sir ? I will choose whichever is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be similar to the [Threaded Fortune Cookie example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/threadedfortuneserver.html) except I wouldn't have the FortuneThread classes derived from QThread itself. I would rather have them derived from [QRunnable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qrunnable.html) and then pass them on to [QThreadPool](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthreadpool.html).

This way, you can put a limit on the number of active threads running in the system and you don't have to constantly keep creating and destroying threads, you just reuse them until your thread pool has been idle for a while.